# Find all cells changed in a column and put it in a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have in `Sheet2` a column that changes with a macro ("New item"). Every time I run that macro, a cell in column C changes its contents.

I want to get ALL the strings added with "new item" macro (from the cells in column C) and put all of them in a variable. I need that variable (containing the contents of cells changed) to send it in an email.

I think I have to use the function below, but I don't know how to do what I need. Th code below doesn't work.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     'if column C changes
     If Target.Address = Sheet(2).Range("C15:C"&lastRow) Then 
         dim var as string

         'put the contents of cells changed in the variable "var"
         var=range("?").Value
     End If       
 End Sub
```

Comment: So you want all of the strings to be concatenated into one string?

Comment: yes. But I don't know how to get that strings

Comment: You could loop through each value within the range and add them into a string. Within the code posted, have you already established the variable `lastRow`?

Comment: yes. With this code: lastRow = Sheet(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row.

Comment: The problem is that I want to add into a string only the cells that changed (with "new item" macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach. And the reason is very simple. `Worksheet_Change` will fire everytime a cell is changed and it will slow down your code.

When that macro starts (The one that changes **Col C** in `Sheet2`), Copy the **Col C** from `Sheet2` in a new temp sheet and just before the macro ends, Copy the **Col C** from `Sheet2` again to the temp sheet and then simply compare the two columns to check what changed.

For example (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet, wsI As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sNewvalues As String

    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    '~~> Copy the column 3 into column 1 of the 
    '~~> new sheet before macro makes changes       
    wsI.Columns(3).Copy wsNew.Columns(1)

    '
    '~~> Rest of the macro
    '

    '~~> Copy the column 3 into column 2 of the 
    '~~> new sheet after macro makes changes
    wsI.Columns(3).Copy wsNew.Columns(2)

    With wsNew
        '~~> Get last row of thenew sheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        '~~> Add a formula in the 3rd column to see if there is any difference
        .Range("C1:C" & lRow).Formula = "=A1=B1"

        '~~> Store the diffrence in a variable
        For i = 1 To lRow
            If .Range("C" & i).Value = "True" Then
                If sNewvalues = "" Then
                    sNewvalues = .Range("B" & i).Value
                Else
                    sNewvalues = sNewvalues & vbNewLine & .Range("B" & i).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        '~~> Display the values
        MsgBox sNewvalues
    End With

    '~~> Delete the temp sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsNew.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why sNewvalues is always empty?

Comment: is your problem sorted?

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: As you can see in my answer post (btw, next time I'll amend the post above, now I can't delete it), I wrote a code that sending an email. My problem is that I can't get the cell change information to send it as an email text. 'myMessage=cs'. The variable 'cs' is what I need to send

Comment: But this is not your original question?

Comment: Yes, it is. This is what I wanted to do. To get the cell change information and put it in a variable. That variable is what I need.

Comment: Can your remove the code from your question which is handling the email part as it may confuse other people and also is irrelevant for this question. With the code that I posted above, were you not able to get the anything for `sNewvalues`?

Comment: ok. I tried the code you posted but the variable sNewvalues doesn't contain anything. Now I'm trying to store the differences between the two columns in a variable

Comment: Did you debug the code and see what was not working?

Comment: I haven't errors. But if I use Immediate Window to check the value of the variable 'sNewvalues', nothing appear in the window. And if I try to use that variable as an email message, my file crush, not responding.

Comment: Debug this line `If .Range("C" & i).Value = "TRUE" Then` and see what happens

Comment: that line loops n times my range and nothing else happens

Comment: Try and change `If .Range("C" & i).Value = "TRUE" Then` to `If .Range("C" & i).Value = "True" Then` Also after this line `Next i` add this line `MsgBox sNewvalues`. What happens?

Comment: In MsgBox I have the string "True" once. Now, the file doesn't crush but the email message is empty. That means that the variable is empty

Comment: Oh ok. I got it. I have changed the code above. Now try it. What do you get in the msgbox?

Comment: I have an error: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range at the line: 'Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")'. I think this error is due to I have nothing in column B in sheet2

Comment: No that is because there is no "Sheet2"

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problems I see are:

- As mentioned above, what is expected to happen if the cells in
  column C below row 14 were changed
  outside of the 'New Item' macro?
- Many macros (possibly 'New Item') use Application.EnableEvents = False during their
  operation and this effectively cancels the WorkSheet_Change event. Need confirmation that this is not the case with 'New Item' macro.

Major rewrite of original response. This includes a sub routine to email the changes out as notification.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C15:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo FallThrough
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim c As Range, cs As String
        For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("C15:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row))
            cs = cs & c.Address(0, 0) & ": " & c.Value & " - " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm") & Chr(10)
        Next c
        cs = Left(cs, Len(cs) - 1)
        Call mcr_Email_Notification("New Item Notification", cs)
    End If
FallThrough:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub mcr_Email_Notification(sSBJ As String, sBDY As String)
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application, objOLMSG As Outlook.MailItem
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOLMSG = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With objOLMSG
        .To = "some.recipient@null.com"  'change this
        .Subject = sSBJ
        .HTMLBody = "<html><body>" & Replace(sBDY, Chr(10), "<br/>") & "</body></html>"
        .send
    End With
    Set objOLMSG = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

The email notification routine requires *Tools, References, Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library* (or equivalent) to be added. I've tested and received the details of the changes/additions made to column C below row 14 in email.

This code belongs in the worksheet code sheet, not a module code sheet. Right-click the worksheet name tab and choose *View Code*. When the VBE opens, paste this into the pane titled something like *Book1 - Sheet2 (Code)*.

Comment: I want that variable because I want to send an email and the email text should be that string (the cell change information).

Comment: @musiclandia - OK, so you would need a Sub that allowed passing a string variable into it and mailed out the string as part of the email body. In that case, the CS variable would be passed over in a Call to the email sub.

Comment: sorry, but I really don't understand what your code does. In Immediate window nothing happens.

Comment: @musiclandia - If you added or changed anything in column C below row 14 then the event should have fired. Paste Application.EnableEvents = True into the Immediate window and press enter or close Excel and restart the program.

Comment: 'cs' is the variable containing the cell change information?

Comment: @musiclandia - That is correct. The changes are stored in the interim variable cs and need to be dealt with before the procedure closes. [Sample workbook](http://tinyurl.com/l39mwq9). Also, please read the second point I made in my Answer response.

Comment: Regarding the second point, is not the case with 'New Item' macro. I'm trying now your code...

Comment: I should use Lotus Notes to send email. I put my code below. I tried your code (as you can see below) but the workbook crush (not responding). Can you help me, pls?

Comment: @musiclandia - It could very well be that your computer's configuration is simply not set up for using an Outlook object for sending email. Beyond checking that your Outlook is set to allow programmatic access you should search for online help that can cover the topic to a deeper degree. Alternately, you can use a proven email send routine based on Lotus Notes.

Comment: the point is that I have to use Lotus, is a requirement. However, thank you a lot for the help. Thanks, really.